# Subsets of sets containing empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why is $\{\emptyset\}$ not a subset of $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$?

It contains this element, but why is it not a subset?

Comment: You're trying to interpret the word "contain" too broadly. For example, a library may be said to *contain* letters, words, sentences, paragraphs, and chapters; but when we think of a library as a set, we generally think of it as a set *of books*, so only the books are members of the set, and not the piecemeal contents/components of the books.

Comment: In addition to the excellent answers below, look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281436/confusion-about-the-null-empty-set-being-contained-in-other-sets -- especially part 3 of the question.

Comment: $\in\ne\subset$.

Comment: Incidentally, there is a word for a set of which every element is also a subset, and that word is "transitive". $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ is not a transitive set, but $\{\{\emptyset\},\emptyset\}$ is.

Answer (score 18):

It is not a subset because its element $\emptyset$ does not belong to the set $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$.

Answer (score 14):

The element $\{\emptyset\}$ and the element $\emptyset$ are different.

$\{\emptyset\}$ is an element of $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$, whereas $\emptyset$ is not.

A subset is a ***set*** whose every element is also a part of the given set.

Thus, the subsets of $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ are $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ and the empty set $\{\}$, also denoted by $\emptyset$.

EDIT:

In one sentence, (Thanks to @Henry)

$\{\{∅\}\}$  has a single element $\{∅\}$ and two subsets $\{\{∅\}\}$ and $∅$, while $\{∅\}$ has a single element $∅$ and two subsets $\{∅\}$ and $∅$.

Comment: You could say that $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ has a single element $\{\emptyset\}$ and two subsets $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ and $\emptyset$.  Meanwhile  $\{\emptyset\}$ has a single element $\emptyset$ and two subsets $\{\emptyset\}$ and $\emptyset$.

Comment: @Henry That's a nice way of saying it, have added it to the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

You can think of sets like plastic bags if you want; the empty set is just a plastic bag with nothing in it, $\{\emptyset\}$ is a plastic bag with another plastic bag in it, and $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ is three layers of plastic bags.

The element relation $A\in B$ means that you could open up bag $B$ and take out $A$.

The subset relation $A\subset B$ means that every object that you could directly take out of $A$ can also be directly taken out of $B$.

So, look at $\{\emptyset\}$. You can "open it up and" take out $\emptyset$, but you can't do that with $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$. Therefore, $\{\emptyset\}\not\subset \{\{\emptyset\}\}$.

Comment: You didn't define B, which makes this answer a bit hard to follow.

Comment: @djechlin Fixed, thanks!

Comment: sure you can, just open the bag and take the plastic bag with nothing inside out.

Comment: "You can think of sets like plastic bags if you want;" what if i don't want?

Comment: @153330 Then you have fun with whatever visualization or lack of visualization you want.

Comment: The bag layers' count would be more obvious if you replace $\emptyset$ with$\{\,\}$ after the first use.