# In the context of regular languages is Ø* = Ø?

Tags: regular-language

In the context of regular expressions is Ø* = Ø? and why?

Comment: Please try to add more context.

Comment: What does that symbol mean here?

Comment: @copper.hat That's the [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) operator, which is standard notation in this context. (Incidentally: to the OP, your question is answered in the third example at the page linked in my previous sentence!)

Comment: @jeff I appreciate your wanting to answer, but the context is regular expressions, the question was answered below correctly.

Comment: @jdoe okay then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Sigma^*$ is the set of all finite strings, each of whose terms is from $\Sigma$ . . . so the answer is **no**!

The empty string, $\epsilon$, is an element of $\emptyset^*$: all of its terms are in $\emptyset$, because there *aren't any*. This is an instance of a more general phenomenon: *universal statements always hold of the emptyset*. For example, every element of the emptyset (or term of the emptystring) is a pink elephant.

And it's not hard to see that $\epsilon$ is the *only* element of $\emptyset^*$ (any string other than $\epsilon$ has at least one term - well, we can't have that here!). So $\emptyset^*=\{\epsilon\},$ which is not the same thing as $\emptyset$ (for the same reason that $\{\emptyset\}\not=\emptyset$; see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281436/confusion-about-the-null-empty-set-being-contained-in-other-sets?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Comment: Thank you! This makes tons of sense, and in hind-site I should have realized. Great answer.